# Jquery included menu not displayed on html page when using bootstrap 5 cdn

Tags: html, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am trialling bootstrap 5 by modifying an existing html which includes a menu added by jquery. When I use the bootstrap 3 cdn the menu is displayed, when I use the bootstrap 5 cdn the menu is not displayed.

Is this a bug with bootstrap 5 or am I doing something wrong in my code?

The jquery is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //Include the menu before the document is ready.
    $("#includedContent").load("Menu.html", function() {
        //Do not allow these items to be selected when a youth member is not displayed
        $(document).on("click", ".dropdown-menu li.disabled a", function() {
            return false;
        });
    });
});
```

The html is:

```
<div id="accountUpdate"  class="container-fluid" style="background-repeat: repeat; background-image: url('images/body-bg.jpg');">

    <div id="includedContent"></div>

    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 bg-warning">
```

Bootstrap 3 cdn:

[image]

Bootstrap 5 cdn:

[image]

This is the code (cut down):

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Edit Awards</title>
    <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow" />
    <meta http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="application-name" content="Award Tracking Application" />
    <meta name="author" content="Glyndwr (Wirrin) Bartlett" />
    <meta name="description" content="A Scout award tracking application" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

    <!-- JQuery -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Validate -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.17.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.17.0/additional-methods.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <!-- <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/5.0.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap Date Picker-->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.20.1/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Text Editor -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/summernote/0.8.12/summernote-bs4.js"></script><!-- 0.8.9 -->

    <!-- Le styles -->
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css"> -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/5.0.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css" />
    
    <!-- Confirm -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-confirm/3.3.0/jquery-confirm.min.css">

    <!-- Text Editor -->
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/summernote/0.8.12/summernote-bs4.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <style type="text/css">
      body {
        padding-top: 40px;
        padding-bottom: 40px;
        background-color: #f5f5f5;
      }

      .form-select {
        max-width: 100%;
        padding: 19px 29px 29px;
        background-color: #fff;
        border: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
        -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
           -moz-border-radius: 5px;
                border-radius: 5px;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.05);
           -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.05);
                box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.05);
      }
      .form-signin .form-heading,
      .form-signin .checkbox {
        margin-bottom: 10px;
      }
      .form-signin input[type="text"],
      .form-signin input[type="password"] {
        font-size: 16px;
        height: auto;
        margin-bottom: 15px;
        padding: 7px 9px;
      }
      .myheader {
        display:flex;
        text-align: center;
      }
      .myimg {
        width: 130px;
        height: auto;
      }
      .pull-right {
        text-align: right;
      }

        /* Tooltip container */

        /* Tooltip text */
        .tooltiptext {
            visibility: hidden;
            width: 120px;
            background-color: #555;
            color: #fff;
            text-align: center;
            padding: 5px 0;
            border-radius: 6px;

            /* Position the tooltip text */
            position: absolute;
            z-index: 1;
            bottom: 125%;
            left: 50%;
            margin-left: -60px;

            /* Fade in tooltip */
            opacity: 0;
            transition: opacity 1s;
        }

        /* Tooltip arrow */
        .tooltiptext::after {
            content: "";
            position: absolute;
            top: 100%;
            left: 50%;
            margin-left: -5px;
            border-width: 5px;
            border-style: solid;
            border-color: #555 transparent transparent transparent;
        }

        /* Show the tooltip text when you mouse over the tooltip container */
        .tooltiptext {
            visibility: visible;
            opacity: 1;
        }

        /* Change the padding */
        .padding-1{
            padding-right:1;
            padding-left:1;
        }

        .req {
          color: red;
        }
        
        .input100, textarea {
            width: 100% !important
        }
        
        .row-eq-height {
          display: -webkit-box;
          display: -webkit-flex;
          display: -ms-flexbox;
          display: flex;
          flex-wrap: wrap;
        }
        
        .datepicker { 
            z-index: 999 !important;
        }
        
        .big-checkbox {
            width: 1.5rem; 
            height: 1.5rem;
            top: 0.5rem;
        }
        
    </style>
    <link href="resources/bootstrap-3.3.7-dist/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- HTML5 shim, for IE6-8 support of HTML5 elements -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="resources/js/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

    <!-- Fav and touch icons -->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="resources/favicon.png">

  </head>

  <body>

    <div id="accountUpdate"  class="container-fluid" style="background-repeat: repeat; background-image: url('images/body-bg.jpg');">
        
        <br><br><br><br>
        <div id="includedContent"></div>

        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 bg-warning">
            <h3>Edit Awards</h3>

        </div>
    </div> <!-- /container -->
    
    <!-- Le javascript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="resources/bootstrap-3.3.7-dist/js/bootstrap-tooltip.js"></script>
    <script src="resources/bootstrap-3.3.7-dist/js/bootstrap-popover.js"></script>

    <script src="js/awardsEdit8.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
//document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event){
    //Include the menu before the document is ready.
    $("#includedContent").load("Menu.html", function() {
        //Do not allow these items to be selected when a youth member is not displayed
        $(document).on("click", ".dropdown-menu li.disabled a", function() {
            return false;
        });
    });
});
```

This is the cut down menu:

```
<head>
    <title>Menu</title>
    <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <meta http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="application-name" content="Award Tracking Application" />
    <meta name="author" content="Glyndwr (Wirrin) Bartlett" />
    <meta name="description" content="A Scout award tracking application" />

    <title>Bootstrap 3 Dropdowns within a Navbar for Award Tracking Application</title>

    <style type="text/css">
        .bs-example{
            margin: 5px;
        }
        
        .ypr_btn{background-color:#ffbf00; color:white; padding: 8px 16px;}

        li.dropdown-header {
            color: #ff0000;
        }
        
        li#logOutAdmin, li#logOutGL, li#logOutGT, li#logOutQM, li#logOutJ, li#logOutC,
            li#logOutS, li#logOutV, li#logOutR, li#logOutNL, li#logOutYM, li#logOutDis,
            li#logOutDS, li#logOutReg, li#logOutSta, li#logOutSS  {
            background-color:red;
        }
            
        li.selectRole  {
            background-color:green;
        }
            
        
        /* News Ticker */
        
        .onoffswitch3
        {
            position: relative; 
            -webkit-user-select:none; 
            -moz-user-select:none; 
            -ms-user-select: none;
        }
        
        .onoffswitch3-checkbox {
            display: none;
        }
        
        .onoffswitch3-label {
            display: block; 
            overflow: hidden; 
            cursor: pointer;
            border: 0px solid #999999; 
            border-radius: 0px;
        }
        
        .onoffswitch3-inner {
            display: block; 
            width: 200%; margin-left: -100%;
            -moz-transition: margin 0.3s ease-in 0s; 
            -webkit-transition: margin 0.3s ease-in 0s;
            -o-transition: margin 0.3s ease-in 0s; 
            transition: margin 0.3s ease-in 0s;
        }
        
        .onoffswitch3-inner > span {
            display: block; 
            float: left; 
            position: relative; 
            width: 50%; 
            height: 30px; 
            padding: 0; 
            line-height: 30px;
            font-size: 14px; 
            color: white; 
            font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif; 
            font-weight: bold;
            -moz-box-sizing: border-box; 
            -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; 
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }
        
        .onoffswitch3-inner .onoffswitch3-active {
            padding-left: 10px;
            background-color: #EEEEEE; 
            color: #FFFFFF;
        }
        
        .onoffswitch3-inner .onoffswitch3-inactive {
            width: 140px;
            padding-left: 16px;
            background-color: #000000; 
            color: #FFFFFF;
            text-align: right;
            white-space: nowrap;
        }
        
        .onoffswitch3-switch {
            display: block; 
            width: 50%; 
            margin: 0px; 
            text-align: center; 
            border: 0px solid #999999;
            border-radius: 0px; 
            position: absolute; 
            top: 0; 
            bottom: 0;
        }
        .onoffswitch3-active .onoffswitch3-switch {
            background: #27A1CA; 
            left: 0;
            width: 160px;
        }
        .onoffswitch3-inactive{
            background: #A1A1A1; 
            right: 0;
            width: 20px;
        }
        .onoffswitch3-checkbox:checked + .onoffswitch3-label .onoffswitch3-inner {
            margin-left: 0;
        }
        
        .glyphicon-remove{
            padding: 3px 0px 0px 0px;
            color: #fff;
            background-color: #000;
            height: 25px;
            width: 25px;
            border-radius: 15px;
            border: 2px solid #fff;
        }
        
        .scroll-text{
            color: #000;
        }
        

    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript"> 
                
        //YPR
        if(sessionStorage.getItem('ssGroupNAS') === 'Y' ){
            $('.ypr_btn').text('NYP');
        }else{
            $('.ypr_btn').text('PAS');
        }

        $('.ypr_btn').click(function(){
            if($(this).text().trim() === 'NYP' ){
                $('.ypr_btn').text('PAS');
                sessionStorage.setItem('ssGroupNAS', "N");
                if(sessionStorage.getItem('ssAccountLevelX') === "Youth Member"){
                    window.location = "AwardOverview.html";
                }else{
                    window.location = "SelectPerson.html";
                }
            }else{
                $('.ypr_btn').text('NYP');
                sessionStorage.setItem('ssGroupNAS', "Y");
                if(sessionStorage.getItem('ssAccountLevelX') === "Youth Member"){
                    window.location = "AwardOverviewYPR.html";
                }else{
                    window.location = "SelectPerson.html";
                }
            }
        });
        
        //Hide Select Role if user is not multi-role
        if (sessionStorage.getItem('ssMultiRole') !== "Y") {
            $('li.selectRole').hide();
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <script>    

        $("#myNavbarAdministrator").hide();
        $("#myNavbarDistrict").hide();
        $("#myNavbarDistrictSection").hide();
        $("#myNavbarGroupLeader").hide();
        $("#myNavbarGroupTreasurer").hide();
        $("#myNavbarLeaderJoey").hide();
        $("#myNavbarLeaderCub").hide();
        $("#myNavbarLeaderScout").hide();
        $("#myNavbarLeaderVenturer").hide();
        $("#myNavbarLeaderRover").hide();
        $("#myNavbarNonLeader").hide();
        $("#myNavbarQuartermaster").hide();
        $("#myNavbarRegion").hide();
        $("#myNavbarRegionSection").hide();
        $("#myNavbarState").hide();
        $("#myNavbarStateSection").hide();
        $("#myNavbarYouthMember").hide();

        switch (true) {
        case (sessionStorage.getItem('ssAccountLevelX') === "Administrator") : $("#myNavbarAdministrator").show(); break;
        case (sessionStorage.getItem('ssAccountLevelX') === "District") : $("#myNavbarDistrict").show(); break;
        case (sessionStorage.getItem('ssAccountLevelX') === "District-Section") : $("#myNavbarDistrictSection").show(); break;
        case (sessionStorage.getItem('ssAccountLevelX') === "Group-Leader") : $("#myNavbarGroupLeader").show(); $("#newsDiv").show(); break;
        case (sessionStorage.getItem('ssAccountLevelX') === "Group-Treasurer") : $("#myNavbarGroupTreasurer").show(); $("#newsDiv").show(); break;
        case (sessionStorage.getItem('ssAccountLevelX') === "Quartermaster") : $("#myNavbarQuartermaster").show(); $("#newsDiv").show(); break;
        case (sessionStorage.getItem('ssAccountLevelX') === "Leader"
                && sessionStorage.getItem('ssGroupSection') === "Joey") : $("#myNavbarLeaderJoey").show(); $("#newsDiv").show(); break;
        case (sessionStorage.getItem('ssAccountLevelX') === "Leader"
            && sessionStorage.getItem('ssGroupSection') === "Cub") : $("#myNavbarLeaderCub").show(); $("#newsDiv").show(); break;
        case (sessionStorage.getItem('ssAccountLevelX') === "Leader"
            && sessionStorage.getItem('ssGroupSection') === "Scout") : $("#myNavbarLeaderScout").show(); $("#newsDiv").show(); break;
        case (sessionStorage.getItem('ssAccountLevelX') === "Leader"
            && sessionStorage.getItem('ssGroupSection') === "Venturer") : $("#myNavbarLeaderVenturer").show(); $("#newsDiv").show(); break;
        case (sessionStorage.getItem('ssAccountLevelX') === "Leader"
            && sessionStorage.getItem('ssGroupSection') === "Rover") : $("#myNavbarLeaderRover").show(); $("#newsDiv").show(); break;
        case (sessionStorage.getItem('ssAccountLevelX') === "Non-leader") : $("#myNavbarNonLeader").show(); $("#newsDiv").show(); break;
        case (sessionStorage.getItem('ssAccountLevelX') === "Region") : $("#myNavbarRegion").show(); break;
        case (sessionStorage.getItem('ssAccountLevelX') === "Region-Section") : $("#myNavbarRegionSection").show(); break;
        case (sessionStorage.getItem('ssAccountLevelX') === "State") : $("#myNavbarState").show(); break;
        case (sessionStorage.getItem('ssAccountLevelX') === "State-Section") : $("#myNavbarStateSection").show(); break;
        case (sessionStorage.getItem('ssAccountLevelX') === "Youth Member") : $("#myNavbarYouthMember").show(); $("#newsDiv").show(); break;
    }
    </script>

    <div class="global-menu">

        <!-- Administrator's menu -->
        <nav id="myNavbarAdministrator" class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#administratorNavbar">
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="administratorNavbar">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">EAP<b class="caret"></b></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="EAP.html">Event Approval Package</a></li>
                                <li><a href="EAPAdministration.html">EAP Administration</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>

                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">Administration<b class="caret"></b></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="AccountAdmin.html">Accounts Admin</a></li>
                                <li><a href="AccountDetails.html">Account Details</a></li>
                                <li><a href="AccountEmailAdmin.html">Account Email</a></li>
                                <li><a href="AccountLeader.html">Account Leader Association</a></li>
                                <li><a href="AccountActivation.html">Account Status Update</a></li>
                                <li><a href="AccountTransfer.html">Account Transfer</a></li>
                                <!-- <li><a href="AccountSection.html">Assign Unit to Account</a></li>  -->
                                <li><a href="AwardsEdit.html">Award Administration</a></li>
                                <li><a href="CaptchaAdministration.html">Captcha Administration</a></li>
                                <li><a href="GroupAdmin.html">Group Administration</a></li>
                                <li><a href="IssueRequestAdmin.html">Issue Administration</a></li>
                                <li><a href="LeaderAdminAdministrator.html">Leader Administration</a></li>
                                <li><a href="LinksAdmin.html">Links</a></li>
                                <li><a href="MealMenus.html">Meal Menus</a></li>
                                <li><a href="NewsAdmin.html">News</a></li>
                                <li><a href="PatrolAdmin.html">Patrol Administration</a></li>
                                <li><a href="PasswordReset.html">Reset Password</a></li>
                                <li><a href="ResourceAdmin.html">Resources</a></li>
                                <li><a href="CatSandwichAdmin.html">Sandwich Administration</a></li>
                                <li><a href="ScoutTransfer.html">Scout Transfer</a></li>
                                <li><a href="SectionAwardOrder.html">Unit Award Order</a></li>
                                <li><a href="SectionAwardType.html">Unit Award Type</a></li>
                                <li><a href="YouthMemberAdmin.html">Youth Member Administration</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="PP.html">Program Planner</a>
                        </li>

                        <!-- 
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">Messages<b class="caret"></b></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="OASSupportReq.html">OAS Support Request</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">My Messages</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Send Account Emails</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        -->

                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">Reports<b class="caret"></b></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="AwardUsage.html">Award Usage</a></li>
                                <li><a href="EmailAddresses.html">Email Addresses</a></li>
                                <li><a href="GroupsAdminReport.html">Groups</a></li>
                                <li><a href="Statistics.html">Statistics</a></li>
                                <li><a href="ProgressChart.html">Progress Chart</a></li>
                                <li><a href="UsageReport.html">Usage</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>

                    </ul>

                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li id="logOutAdmin"><a href="Login.html"><font color="ffffff"><b>Log out</b></font></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
            </div>

        </nav>

    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Do you know what that grey line is above the word 'Edit'? Also, is it possible the menu is above the top and a margin is needed? And has the 'path' to the menu changed?

Comment: Can you post the complete BS5 code that’s generating the page (and not just a picture of the page)? Without the code to duplicate the problem, it’s pretty difficult to provide any suggestions.

Comment: Hi Wazz, the grey line is the div that should contain the menu. I added some <br> above the div to test this any everything moved down the page. No, the path has not changed :-).

Comment: Hi Rich, pardon my ignorance; but, what is BS5 code? Do you want me to publish the js and html files. If yes then I will create a minimum code demo.

Comment: Hi, can you show `Menu.html` as well?

Comment: Glyn - BS5 is your bootstrap 5 code. You're going from Bootstrap 3 to 5, so to understand what's happening, people need to see your code for the menu file (either as BS3, which won't work or BS5 so it can be reviews.  *To reply to a comment, you have to use @rich, otherwise the comment poster doesn't know you responded (Hi doesn't work).*

Comment: @RichDeBourke Thank you.  I have posted the cut down menu.

Comment: @Swati I have added the cut down menu code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Bootstrap 5 (BS5) has changed quite a bit from Bootstrap 3 (BS3), you’re going to need to recreate your pages using BS5 classes.

The menu code that you added to your question is for BS3. I used that code as the basis for creating the same concept using BS5. It is a little different. For example, BS3 uses a 14px font-size while BS5 uses a 16px font-size. You could override all of those types of changes, but with the current screen resolutions that are available, a using BS5’s standards may be better for your users.

### Menu recreated in BS5

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<style>
    .dropdown-item {
        padding: 0.1875rem 1rem;
        line-height: normal;
    }
</style>

<div class="global-menu">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <button class="navbar-toggler ms-auto" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                <ul class="navbar-nav w-100 me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown1" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                            EAP
                        </a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown1">
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href=" EAP.html">Event Approval Package</a></li>
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href=" EAPAdministration.html">EAP Administration</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown2" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                            Administration
                        </a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown2">
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="AccountAdmin.html">Accounts Admin</a></li>
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="AccountDetails.html">Account Details</a></li>
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="AccountEmailAdmin.html">Account Email</a></li>
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="AccountLeader.html">Account Leader Association</a></li>
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="AccountActivation.html">Account Status Update</a></li>
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="AccountTransfer.html">Account Transfer</a></li>
                            <!-- <li><aclass="dropdown-item" href="AccountSection.html">Assign Unit to Account</a></li>  -->
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="AwardsEdit.html">Award Administration</a></li>
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="CaptchaAdministration.html">Captcha Administration</a></li>
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="GroupAdmin.html">Group Administration</a></li>
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="IssueRequestAdmin.html">Issue Administration</a></li>
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="LeaderAdminAdministrator.html">Leader Administration</a></li>
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="LinksAdmin.html">Links</a></li>
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="MealMenus.html">Meal Menus</a></li>
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="NewsAdmin.html">News</a></li>
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="PatrolAdmin.html">Patrol Administration</a></li>
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="PasswordReset.html">Reset Password</a></li>
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="ResourceAdmin.html">Resources</a></li>
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="CatSandwichAdmin.html">Sandwich Administration</a></li>
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="ScoutTransfer.html">Scout Transfer</a></li>
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="SectionAwardOrder.html">Unit Award Order</a></li>
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="SectionAwardType.html">Unit Award Type</a></li>
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="YouthMemberAdmin.html">Youth Member Administration</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="PP.html">Program Planner</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown3" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                            Reports
                        </a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown3">
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="AwardUsage.html">Award Usage</a></li>
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="EmailAddresses.html">Email Addresses</a></li>
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="GroupsAdminReport.html">Groups</a></li>
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="Statistics.html">Statistics</a></li>
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="ProgressChart.html">Progress Chart</a></li>
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="UsageReport.html">Usage</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item ms-md-auto">
                        <a type="button" href="Login.html" class="btn btn-danger">Log out</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
</div>
```

I did change the line-height and the vertical padding on the menu items so they fit better on a page.

*Using the @ and username did help in replying to previous comments — doing so delivers a message to my inbox.*

Comment: Hi Rich, This is excellent! One final question. Should each id="navbarDropdown1" be unique (you have multiple of the same id)?

Answer (score 1):

Check the DOM. Is the menu code there? if yes so you most change menu css position styles and or z-index in inspect to fixed it.

Comment: What is the DAM and how do I check it please?

Comment: Added class="includedContent " to the div and  .includedContent {
   z-index: 100;
   position: absolute;
  } This just moved the small grey box down. I tried -1 and this hid the small grey box behind the wallpaper image.

Comment: Sorry DOM , Run your web page and go to inspect element of browser, and check html to find menu

Comment: Hi Hossein, This helped a lot and lead me on the right path to change the nav to <nav id="myNavbarAdministrator" class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-expand-md navbar-sm navbar-xs">. Then Rich came up with the full answer. Thank you very much.